# Matching html-tags in vi with regex

Tags: regex, vim, vi, regular-language

I want to match html-tags with regular expressions in vi.

```
<html>  
    <body>  
        hununuhu  
    </body>
</html>
```

and I am successful with this regular expression, which matches all the tags:

```
<\/*\(\w*\)>
```

But not with this one, where the star is replaced by the ?-Operator (which is more accureate in my opinion):

```
<\/?\(\w*\)>
```

Why is this one not successful ?

Gruß, Andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape the question-mark as well:

```
<\/\?\(\w*\)>
```